# What are "retainedNodes" in LLVMs debug metadata?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-construction, llvm, debug-information

Using the LLVM 8.0.1 library, I try to create the debug info for a function with the following code:

```cpp
DIFile *Unit = DebugBuilder->createFile(CompileUnit->getFilename(), CompileUnit->getDirectory());
DIScope *FContext(Unit);

DISubprogram *SP = DebugBuilder->createFunction(
    FContext, def->Name, def->Name, Unit, LineNo,
    CreateFunctionType(ft, CompileUnit->getFile()), 0);

func->setSubprogram(SP);
```

This, however, results in IR like the following:

```
define i32 @main(i32 %y) !dbg !3 {
entry:
  ret i32 2
}
    ; ...
!3 = !DISubprogram(name: "main", linkageName: "main", scope: !2, file: !2, type: !4, spFlags: 0, retainedNodes: !7)
    ; ...
!7 = <temporary!> !{}
```

Which, upon calling `DebugBuilder->finalize()`, throws `Assertion failed: !N->isTemporary() && "Expected all forward declarations to be resolved"`

I have not found a description of the `retainedNodes` field in the official reference nor other tutorials, and web searches only lead to uncommented sections of the LLVM source. What is the meaning or purpose of this field? How is a temporary node created there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solved by adding, before generating the `DebugBuilder`,

```
TheModule->addModuleFlag(llvm::Module::Warning, "CodeView", 1);
```

... as explained apparently *nowhere* in the official documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the LLVM C API (using `inkwell-rs` as a wrapper). I fixed this problem by invoking `LLVMDIBuilderCreateFunction` with `IsDefinition = true` and `IsLocalToUnit = true`. This keeps the `retainedNodes` metadata node, but its value is empty metadata (`!{}`) instead of a temporary.

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem by finalizing the subprogram explicitly with finalizeSubprogram.

```cpp
DebugBuilder->finalizeSubprogram(SP);
```

This seems to resolve the temporary, but I still got some warnings, when compiling the generated IR.

If you make the function a definition by adding the `DISubprogram::SPFlagDefinition` flag to `DebugBuilder->createFunction` call, retainedNodes will be set to an empty node instead of a temporary.